# What is wrong with my algorithm/code?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. Currently, I am trying to get the averages of everything with the same temp (ex temp 18 = 225 conductivity average, temp 19 = 15 conductivity average, etc).

Could someone tell me if this is a simple coding mistake or a algorithm mistake and offer some help to fix this problem?

```
temp = [18,18,19,19,20]
conductivity = [200,250,20,10,15]

tempcheck = temp[0];
conductivitysum = 0;
datapoint = 0;

assert len(temp) == len(conductivity)

for i in range(len(temp)):
    if tempcheck == temp[i]:
        datapoint+=1
        conductivitysum+=conductivity[i]
    else:
        print conductivitysum/datapoint
        datapoint=0
        conductivitysum=0
        tempcheck=temp[i]
```

For some reason, it is printing out

> 225
>
> 10

When it should be printing out

> 225
>
> 15
>
> 15

Comment: `print float(conductivitysum)/datapoint`

Comment: Yes, but that does not solve the problem. What I am getting in the output is 225, and then 10

Comment: It's not a weird reason, that's what you told it to do. You reset datapoint to 0 instead of to 1, and conductivitysum to 0 instead of putting the current value in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the else to:

```
for i in range(len(temp)):
    if tempcheck == temp[i]:
        datapoint+=1
        conductivitysum+=conductivity[i]
    else:
        print conductivitysum/datapoint
        datapoint=1
        conductivitysum=conductivity[i]
        tempcheck=temp[i]
```

When you get to the pair (19, 20) you need to keep them and count one datapoint, not 0 datapoints. At the moment you are skipping them and only keeping the next one - (19, 10).

Alternatively, rewrite it as

```
>>> temp = [18,18,19,19,20]
>>> conductivity = [200,250,20,10,15]

# build a dictionary to group the conductivities by temperature
>>> groups = {}
>>> for (t, c) in zip(temp, conductivity):
...     groups[t] = groups.get(t, []) + [c]
...     

# view it
>>> groups
{18: [200, 250], 19: [20, 10], 20: [15]}

# average the conductivities for each temperature
>>> for t, cs in groups.items():
        print t, float(sum(cs))/len(cs)
... 
18 225
19 15
20 15
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

in else clause
put :

```
conductivitysum=0
datapoint=0
tempcheck = temp[i]
conductivitysum+=conductivity[i]
datapoint+=1
```

because when you go to else clause, you miss that particular conductivity of i. It doesn't get saved. So before moving to next i, save that conductivity

Comment: I sure would like to know the reasons for downvote. That will be helpful in my learning process :)

Comment: I upvoted your first answer; when you added code and I read it, your code was wrong, so I removed my upvote. It may have looked like a downvote. Now you've edited again with code that looks right, I've re-upvoted.

Comment: thanks. Its just I gave lines to append after tempcheck = temp[i] assuming the OP will understand that rest all code has to be kept intact. After the downvote (which apparently wasn't one) I figured it wasn't good idea to give incomplete piece of code. So changed it back :) thanks for the explanation. Points reciprocated :)

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this code, the first thing that popped into my head was the `zip` function. I hope that the following code is what you want.

```
temp = [18,18,19,19,20]
conductivity = [200,250,20,10,15]

assert len(temp) == len(conductivity)

# Matches each temp value to its corresponding conductivity value with zip

relations = [x for x in zip(temp, conductivity)]

for possible_temp in set(temp): # Takes each possible temparature (18,19,20)
    total = 0
    divide_by = 0

    # The next four lines of code will check each match and figure out the
    # summed total conductivity value for each temp value and how much it
    # should be divided by to create an average.

    for relation in relations:
        if relation[0] == possible_temp:
            total += relation[1]
            divide_by += 1
    print(int(total / divide_by))
```